# Getting a NodeList of the HTML tags in Mithril

Tags: javascript, dom, mithril.js

Is there a way of having a NodeList of the HTML tags in Mithril? I need to get the width of the blocks. Something like that on vanilla js:

```js
const blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.blocks'));

const styles = blocks
  .map((item) => item.getBoundingClientRect())
  .map((item) => item.width);

const widthOfTheBlocks = styles.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0) + 'px';
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the use-case?  Usually mithril is working with components that are nested within the larger DOM.  So maybe you'd try to calculate the total width of a component after it rendered to try to trigger something.  Is that what you are trying todo?

Comment: So for example with a mithril component you'd save off the root node of that component during the oncreate lifecycle method and then during the onupdate lifecycle method you'd navigate the nodes below the component root node to compute the bounding client rect and do something based on that data.

Answer (score 2):

With typical DOM scripting, the DOM elements are pre-existing, and you would need to make sure they had identifiable selector (in this case the `blocks` class), and then elsewhere use that selector to get a Javascript reference to them, with `document.querySelectorAll`.

But with Mithril, you're declaring and referencing the DOM elements in the same place, so you don't need either of these methods: instead you attach a [lifecycle method](https://mithril.js.org/lifecycle-methods.html#oncreate) on the appropriate node and save the reference to a local variable.

The lifecycle methods expose a [`vnode`](https://mithril.js.org/vnodes.html#structure) argument representing the virtual DOM entity: this contains a `dom` property which exposes the rendered DOM element.

The essential mechanism to save a reference inside a component is as follows:

```
function MyComponent(){   // The component to contain the logic
  let dom                 // The variable to store our DOM reference

  return {
    view : () => 
      m('.MyElement', {   // The virtual DOM element
        oncreate(vnode){  // The `oncreate` lifecycle method to access the `vnode`
          dom = vnode.dom // Save the dom reference to our variable
        }
      })
  }
}
```

Below, I've written a little sandbox demo that uses your width calculation script in a slightly more complex scenario: Here there's a variable number of blocks, which are added to and removed over time; we declare a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store them, and for each item we declare an `oncreate` method to `add` it to the set, and an `onremove` to `delete` it. I've used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) to extract the `dom` reference straight from the methods; later, we use a slightly tweaked version of your width accumulation code, using the 2nd argument of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#array_from_a_nodelist) to extract the `width`.

```js
function Blocks(){
  const blocks = new Set

  return {
    view: ({attrs: {count}}) => [
      m('.container',
        Array.from({length: count}, (_, index) => 
          m('.block', {
            oncreate({dom}){
              blocks.add(dom)
            },

            onremove({dom}){
              blocks.delete(dom)
            },
          }, index + 1)
        ),
      ),

      m('button', {
        onclick(){
          const styles = Array.from(
            blocks,
            (item) => item.getBoundingClientRect().width
          )

          const widthOfTheBlocks = styles.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0) + 'px';

          alert(widthOfTheBlocks)
        }
      }, 'Alert width'),
    ]
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, function App(){
  let count = 1

  return {
    view: () => [
      m('h1', 'Width reader'),

      m('label', 
        'Number of blocks: ',

        m('input[type=number][min=0][max=9][size=4]', {
          value: count,
          oninput(e){
            count = e.target.value
          },
        }),
      ),

      m(Blocks, {count}),
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
```